# How do I check all boxes in Alfred Snippets?

Tags: alfred

I imported the Alfred Snippets Emoji pack except all the boxes to enable the many, many emojis are unchecked. How do I quickly check all these boxes? Manually checking each box will take a long while. 
[image]

Comment: So this isn't a bad way to do use emojis, but I thought that maybe you're not aware that there is a pop-up list of emojis that you can conjure via a shortcut: https://support.apple.com/en-ke/HT201586 I should add that it's possible to change the shortcut if it doesn't feel right.

Comment: I was not, thank you! I would upvote but I can't yet. 

Comment: That's fine. I considered posting this as an answer, as I believe it to be the better way to use emojis, but the posted answer is directly addressing the issue you have in the question, so it's a better fit in that sense. You can by the way click the checkmark on the left side of the answer below the point counter to mark an answer as correct.

Comment: @Joonas It might be the better way for you to use emojis, but I actually got intrigued about the Alfred snippet pack from reading/answering this question. I rarely ever use them as I find the built-in way too clunky to use. Just typing  is much nicer to me. Thanks vivian for bringing this to my attention! 

Comment: @Lizzan, I don't know, I'd say the native method works pretty much the same. The link I posted implies you need to use the mouse, but you can actually just conjure the pop-up with the shortcut and then type the name of an emoji and press enter to place it. You can also navigate the list with arrow keys or the mouse. So it is a few more steps: shortcut + type in the name or select a recently used emoji + enter... But I would argue it's not a huge ordeal given that you don't need to remember what each emoji is called to use them, which is the only downside of text expansion in this instance.

Comment: @Joonas I'd say the official method is nice if you don't know the exact name of the emoji you're looking for, sure.  But once I do know it, I'd rather just keep typing than starting a search in a separate "window", even if it's much the same number of key presses. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select the first snippet by clicking on it.
2. Scroll to the bottom and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking the last snippet (or press <kbd>⌘+A</kbd> to select all)
3. Right click on a snippet to bring up the context menu
4. Mouse over Auto Expansion and click "Set Allowed"

[image: Screen shot of Set Allowed in context menu]

All the check boxes should now be checked.